# Creating slim Docker image with Pillow numpy scipy PyBrain

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to create slim image with `gunicorn Pillow numpy scipy PyBrain` dependencies. However whatever I do, my image size becomes above 500 MB. Is there a any trick to decrease the size of the docker image?

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine

RUN echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk --update add --no-cache \
    lapack-dev \
    gcc \
    freetype-dev

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    gfortran \
    musl-dev \
    g++ \
    jpeg-dev \
    zlib-dev 

RUN apk add --update tini

COPY requirements.txt /app/
COPY app/ /app/
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install numpy==1.13.3
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apk del .build-deps

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
CMD ["gunicorn", "-w 3", "-b :8080", "app:app"]
```

Comment: I believe this is a common issue with the python docker images. Your pip requirements alone take `292Mb` I measured in a virtualenv. Your starting docker image `python:2.7-alpine` is  `25Mb`. Measuring the size of your apk add packages is `228 Mb`.

Answer (score 0):

Build dependencies need to be removed in the same `RUN` command to avoid them being stored into their own layer. For example:

```
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    gfortran \
    musl-dev \
    g++ \
    jpeg-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && apk del .build-deps
```

Note that this will result in additional build time every time requirements are updated because `apk` commands will be executed as well. If that is not acceptable for your application, then just remove the `RUN apk del .build-deps` step since that doesn't reduce image size, but it increases it given that the addition/removal of packages happen in different image layers.